# Adding private Maven repo hosted on Github as dependency in Gradle

Tags: git, maven, android-studio, github, gradle

I have a private project on Github (you can't clone or even find the project without being added as a contributor), and a branch on it for Maven artifacts generated in this project.

I have another project (also private) for Android, and I am wondering if there is any way to add the most recent versions of the Maven artifacts as a dependency in this Android project (or indeed any version), through Gradle.

Earlier similar questions on this site tell me that Github has no basic HTTP authentication, and I looked at jitpack.io but even if I logged into my Github, it still couldn't find the repo I was interested in. If it makes any difference, I don't own this project, a partner does, but I have access to it.

Comment: Have you considered using an Amazon S3 for the artifact storage?  It's supported by gradle natively and data stored in s3's is relatively cheap.

Comment: shoot totally didn't think of that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an Amazon S3 bucket for artifact storage.  Here is an example of how to setup the dependencies to download from s3

```
// add s3 for dependency download
repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://someS3Bucket/maven2"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey "someKey"
            secretKey "someSecret"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible for Google Cloud Storage too?